# Why can't I pass params into link_to onto controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following link_to method in my haml view:

```
= link_to(t('compare.view_as_graph'), compare_graph_projects_url, remote: true)
```

When I click this link, I want the params of my url which has this extension:

```
p/compare?project_0=MySQL&project_1=fast-math
```

to pass into a compare_controller that I've created with the following code inside of it.

```
def projects_graph
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

Currently the code gives me this params hash when I inspect it:

```
{"controller"=>"compare", "action"=>"projects_graph", "query"=>nil}
```

This is not what I need. I need the project_0 and project_1 portions. 
This is my route from routes.rb

```
 get 'p/graph', to: 'compare#projects_graph', as: :compare_graph_projects
```

I've tried a number of things such as this

```
compare_graph_projects_url(params)
compare_graph_projects_url(opts[:graph])
= link_to(t('compare.view_as_graph'), compare_graph_projects_url, data: {params: params}, remote: true)
```

(The opts[:graph] was a variable in haml that contains the params)

What am I doing wrong here? Why can't I grab the params with the AJAX request?

The only other thing that I can think of was doing `request.referer` to get the actual header information but this doesn't seem very railsy. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: project_0=MySQL&project_1=fast-math Are these params static or dynamic?

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply sansarp? What do you mean by static or dynamic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass in the values inside url helper like this:

```
= link_to(t('compare.view_as_graph'), compare_graph_projects_url(project_0: "Your value", project_1: "your value"), remote: true)
```

Then you can access them in controller like this:

```
def projects_graph
  @proj_0 = params[:project_0]
  @proj_1 = params[:project_1]
end
```

You should also read about [`action controllers`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html) for more details on how things work.

Comment: Thanks Mandeep, I see my mistake now. The url argument needed to be in hash format and not just a variable despite something like this compare_graph_projects_url(@instance_variable)

Answer (score 2):

You should pass your parameters to the route helper like this:

```html
compare_graph_projects_url(project_0: opts[:graph][project_0], project_1: opts[:graph][project_0])
```

Comment: while you will be posting answers, please try to make them neat well edited and drafted.